# Extract multiple Elements from a JSON dict using python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

In Python, i have my JSON formated the following way:

```
lists = [
    { 
      "id": 1,
      "data": {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Title1",
        "list_category": "green",
        "list_group": ["foo", "bar"],
        "tag_Number": ["One","Three","Four","Seven"],
        "tag_ABCD": ["B", "C", "D", "E"]
       }
     },
     { 
      "id": 2,
      "data": {
        "id": "32",
        "title": "Title32",
        "list_category": "blue",
        "list_group": ["foo2", "bar2"],
        "tag_Number": ["One","Three","Four","Seven"],
        "tag_ABCD": ["B", "C", "D", "E"]
       },
...
```

I want do write different funtions to extract different kind of data from these list. For example, to extract the title and id, I wrote the following funtion:

```
 def getTitle():
        index_list = []
        index_dict = dict()
        for x in checklists:
            val = ast.literal_eval(x["data"])
            Index = dict(id= x['id'], title = val["title"])
            index_dict[x['id']]=Index
        return index_dict
```

My problem is, when i try to extract other values, for example `tag_ABCD`, I try to change my function the following way:

```
 def getTag():
        index_list = []
        index_dict = dict()
        for x in checklists:
            val = ast.literal_eval(x["data"])
            _val = ast.literal_eval(x["val"])
            Index = dict(id= x['id'], tag = _val["tag_ABCD"])
            index_dict[x['id']]=Index
        return index_dict
```

But it wont return the correct element.

Another Problem (side question..):
Why isn't it possible to return my data when i want to add a third element to the dict?

```
 def getTitle():
        index_list = []
        index_dict = dict()
        for x in checklists:
            val = ast.literal_eval(x["data"])
            Index = dict(id= x['id'], title = val["title"], list_category = val["list_category"])
            index_dict[x['id']]=Index
        return index_dict
```

For every one of my variatoins, I get the same error:

> KeyError: 'list_category'

Comment: Thanks for the hints, i edited out the two typos i made, my bad. And thanks, i will take a look at it when i get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nifty way to write the functions you need would be with list comprehension and dict comprehension. See here for how these work : https://www.smallsurething.com/list-dict-and-set-comprehensions-by-example/

The code could look like this :

```
def title_id(the_list):
  return {id: title for (id, title) in [(i["id"], i["title"]) for i in the_list]}
```

As for your error around list_category, I bet one of the dicts in your list doesn't have that key. To see what's going on, use try-except and print val in the case of a key error.